# From $E[XY]$ deriving $E[X^2]$ doesn't match up!

Tags: probability, random-variables, expected-value, variance

$$E[XY] = \sum_{x\epsilon X }^{} \sum_{y\epsilon Y}^{} xy \cdot P(xy)$$

so if we let $Y=X$ we get

$$E[X^2] = \sum_{x \in X }^{} \sum_{y \in X}^{} xy *P(xy)$$

but $$E[X^2] = \sum_{x \in X}^{}x^2P(x)$$,

if I try these to equations with a simple example like X = {1, 2, 3} each with probability 1/3, I get different answers.

Can someone please let me know where I went wrong in my logic ?

Also, let's say X has 5 elements and Y has 5 elements, would X*Y have 25 elements? If so, why doesn't X*X have 25 elements, and is only understood to mean each value of an element is simply squared?

Comment: There's is no such thing as P(xy). What you should have written is P(X=x,Y=y), which in the second case will be zero unless X=y.

Comment: why would is be 0 unless x=y?  Does all x E X, mutually exclusive from each other? If so why?

Comment: $X^2=XY$ where $Y=X$. So your formula gives $\sum_{x,y} xyP(X=x,Y=y)$. But since $Y=X$, $P(X=x,Y=y)$ is zero unless $x=y$ as $X$ cannot equal to two distinct values simultaneously. Thus you end up with $\sum_{x,y,x=y} xyP(X=x,Y=y)=\sum_{x} x^2P(X=x)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You replace $x\cdot y$ by $x\cdot x=x^2$ only.
$$E[X^2] = \sum_{x\epsilon X }^{} \sum_{y\epsilon Y}^{} x^2 \cdot P(x,y)$$

$$= \sum_{x\epsilon X }^{} x^2 \cdot \sum_{y\epsilon Y}^{}   P(x,y)= \sum_{x\epsilon X }^{} x^2 \cdot P(x), $$

where $P(x)$ are the corresponding  probabilities of $X$.

Comment: Why only consider when y=x (basically considering x*y = x^2)?

Comment: @LameloBall to answer your question I ask you a question first :-): what is the value of x if I tell you that x is equal to 1?

Comment: @LameloBall At $\mathbb E(XY)$ you replace Y by X $\rightarrow \mathbb E(XX)$. Thex same yo do at $xy$.

Comment: @LameloBall Also see the  atricle at wiki about the Law of the unconscious statistician [1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician#Joint_distributions).  $$\operatorname{E}[g(X, Y)] = \sum_y \sum_x g(x, y) p_{X, Y}(x, y)$$

Comment: @callculus42 
$$E[X^2] = \sum_{x \in X }^{} \sum_{y \in X}^{} xy *P(xy)$$ is the same thing as your saying because x and y are both in X; the only difference is that you only don't include any of the terms where x != y, why is this? (the only explanation would be because P(x, y)=0 for all x!=y, is that the case ?)

Comment: @LameloBall That's true. In this case you don't regard the $p_{X,Y}(x,y)$, where $x\neq y$.

Answer (score 1):

Let's go back to a simple numeric example to illustrate the difference.

Let $X$ be the outcome of a fair six-sided die that is colored green; i.e., $$\Pr[X = x] = \frac{1}{6}, \quad x \in \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6\}.$$  Similarly, let $Y$ be the outcome of a second fair six-sided die, which is colored red.  You toss both dice and observe the outcome.  What is the average of the product of the outcome?  For example, you could have $X = 2$, $Y = 3$, and $XY = 6$; we want $\operatorname{E}[XY]$.  This is simply
$$\begin{align}
\operatorname{E}[XY] &= \sum_{x=1}^6 \sum_{y=1}^6 xy \Pr[X = x, Y = y] \\
&\overset{\text{ind}}{=} \sum_{x=1}^6 \sum_{y=1}^6 xy \Pr[X = x]\Pr[Y = y] \\
&= \sum_{x=1}^6 x \Pr[X = x] \sum_{y=1}^6 y \Pr[Y = y] \\
&= \operatorname{E}[X]\operatorname{E}[Y] \\
&= \frac{7}{2} \cdot \frac{7}{2} \\
&= \frac{49}{4}.
\end{align}$$

Now, suppose instead we want the average value of the *square* of the green die *only*, ignoring the red die's outcome completely.  This is the meaning of $\operatorname{E}[X^2]$.  The set of outcomes for the square of the green die's value is $X^2 \in \{1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36\}$, since $X \in \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6\}$.  So we must have
$$\operatorname{E}[X^2] = \sum_{x=1}^6 x^2 \Pr[X = x] = \frac{1 + 4 + 9 + 16 + 25 + 36}{6} = \frac{91}{6}.$$

This shows how the two expectations are not the same.  It would have been the same if, for instance, the red die was somehow magically linked to the green one, and always showed the same number as the green.  But it is not, so you could have gotten $XY = 6$ but this outcome is impossible for $X^2$, as $6$ is not a perfect square.

When you have the product of two random variables, say $X$ and $Y$, the outcome of one variable may not be completely determined by the outcome of the other.  We can see from the dice example that $XY = X^2$ only if the variable $Y$ is perfectly correlated and equal to $X$.  It is not sufficient that $Y$ simply obeys the same distribution as $X$ does:  its outcome must be *identical* to the outcome of $X$.